# Referencing local angular.js does not work

Tags: angularjs

I'm beginning to work with AngularJS and am having trouble working with a local copy of the angular.js file.  Below is the sample I am trying to get to work.  When I reference the CDN script, the page correctly displays 'Hello, World'.  When I reference the local script, the binding does not occur.  The browser is able to locate the local angular.js file, it just doesn't seem to perform the binding.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        function HelloController($scope) {
            $scope.greeting = { text: "Hello" };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Angular 1.0.4?

Comment: Your local copy is probably a much more recent version than 1.0.4, which is completely obsolete. Global functions can't be controllers anymore in recent versions.

Comment: No reason.  Attempting my first Hello World Angular app today.

Comment: What version is your local copy of angularjs?

Comment: Local version is 1.3.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was starting out with 1.3.15 would do something like this:

```
<html ng-app="main.app">

<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('main.app', [])
  .controller('HelloController', function () {
    var self = this;

    this.greeting = { text: "Hello" };
})

</script>
</head>

 <body ng-controller="HelloController as HelloCtrl">
   <p>{{HelloCtrl.greeting.text}}, World</p>
 </body>

</html>
```

This follows the latest styles of angular coding